# Int main() doesn't return anything

Tags: c

```
int maxInd (int v[], int N)
{
    int max, ind;
    for (i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        if (v[i] > v[i + 1]) { ind = i; }
    }
    return ind;
}


int main()
{
    int v[10] = {1,2,3,4,5,3,7,6,8};
    return maxInd(v, 8);
}
```

I have this function, where I'm supposed to return the index of the highest int. I think it's correct given that it runs with no errors, but it just doesn't return the index.

What am I doing wrong? Sorry for beginner question.

Thanks!

Comment: This code seems to be prone to undefined behaviour: you're reading from `ind` which is not (always) initialized. Also, it's accessing the array out-of-bounds.

Comment: And what's the point of the `max` variable?

Comment: Have you tried debugging it?

Comment: max was supposed to find its max int.but i only want its index.but i get no return.

Comment: Maybe you want `printf("%d", maxInd(v, 8));`? And where have you declared `i`?

Comment: ok it returned now with printf, but it gave me 6, which is the index of int 7

Comment: @RiczS , And what is the expected result? Try `ind = i+1;` instead of `ind = i;`. Returning a value from `main` doesn't (usually) print it. The return value is mainly used to check if the program executed successfully. Usually, 0 (or `EXIT_SUCCESS` from `stdlib.h`) is used to signify successful termination and `-1` (or `EXIT_FAILURE` from `stdlib.h`) is used to denote failure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

sample to fix

```
int maxInd (int v[], int N){
    int ind = 0;
    for(int i=0;i<N;i++){
        if(v[i]>v[ind]){
            ind=i;
        }
    }
    return ind;
}
```

Comment: It seems that the [OP want to print the value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30422842/int-main-doesnt-return-anything#comment48931397_30422842). I suggest adding about a `printf` in `main`.

Answer (score 0):

Your function does not search the maximum element in an array. it should be define the following way

```
#include <stdio.h>

size_t maxInd( const int a[], size_t n )
{
    size_t max = 0;

    for ( size_t i = 1; i < n; i++ )
    {
        if ( a[max] < a[i] ) max = i;
    }

    return max;
}


int main( void )
{
    int a[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 3, 7, 6, 8 };

    size_t max = maxInd( a, sizeof( a ) / sizeof( *a ) );

    printf( "The maximum element of the array is %d at position &zu\n", a[max], max );

    return 0;
}
```